# Flarum Homestead Laravel subdirectory 404

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, forum, flarum

I am trying to set up Flarum in a subdirectory of **Laravel**. The installation went fine, but I have a few problems.

If I try to access **admin panel** -> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Notifications -> 404 Not Found GET GET http://axiom.app/forum/api/notifications

Make a discussion -> 404 Not Found POST http://axiom.app/forum/api/discussions

Running homestead with nginx. This is the configuration block

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name axiom.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/Code/axiom/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    location /api { try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$query_string; }
    location /admin { try_files $uri $uri/ /admin.php?$query_string; }
location /flarum {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/axiom.app-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
 location ~* \.html$ {
        expires -1;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 1M;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml
               application/javascript
               application/json
               application/vnd.ms-fontobject
               application/x-font-ttf
               application/x-web-app-manifest+json
               application/xhtml+xml
               application/xml
               font/opentype
               image/svg+xml
               image/x-icon
               text/css
               text/plain
               text/xml;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/axiom.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/axiom.app.key;
}
```

Any idea how to fix this? **Thanks** in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the answer.**

```
 location /api { try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$query_string; }
 location /admin { try_files $uri $uri/ /admin.php?$query_string; }
```

need to be relative to flarum

```
 location /forum/api { try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/api.php?$query_string; }
 location /forum/admin { try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/admin.php?$query_string; }
 location /forum/ { try_files $uri $uri/ /forum/index.php?$query_string; }
```

The last line needs to be added to the **block**.